# What is the difference between "abstract parse tree" and "parse tree"?

Tags: terminology, parse-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between parse tree and AST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026517/whats-the-difference-between-parse-tree-and-ast)

I need to know what is the difference between abstract parse trees and parse trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree):

> Parse trees are distinct from abstract syntax trees (also known simply as syntax trees), in that their structure and elements more concretely reflect the syntax of the input language.